# Access the UID of the user registering to assign a second unique identifier in Drupal

Tags: drupal, registration

I'm trying to add a legacy requirement for a site transferring into Drupal. That requirement is that there is another non-Core unique identifier. I'm using the following...

```
function hook_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {

}
```

and was then trying to take the UID by using the following...

```
$userIdentifier = $uid[user][entity_keys][id];
```

But that just lead to an error

Because previously I have created a table in the Field UI.

I tried the form part of the Rules UI but the anonymous user fix didn't work, any ideas on what might work?

Note: I should just point out that I've asked this on drupal.stackexchange.com before and am still working on it (here's the original post: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46451/hook-user-presave-at-user-registration-how-to-get-field-data-field-set-to-auto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time `hook_user_insert()` is fired the account has been saved, so you can get the user id straight out of the object:

```
$uid = $account->uid;
```